# Javascript async return bool to outer function

Tags: javascript, callback, phantomjs, casperjs

I need to return a boolean from a function t, like this:

```
    function(t){   
        //Do Something 
        return resultBool;
    }
```

But I when I have an async function (CasperJS) that determines the outcome, how would I do this using a callback? I tried something like this, but it doesnt seem to work (I think the function is simply returning the return value of t.withFrame, which is always true).

```
function(t){    
            function findElementInFrame(callback)
            {
                try{
                    t.withFrame("etravelframe", function(){
                        if(t.exists('#outFlight1------') == true){             
                            callback(true);           
                        } 
                        else{                                               
                            callback(false);                            
                        } 
                    });
                } catch(err){
                    //return false;
                }
            }            


            return findElementInFrame(function(bool){return bool;});

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call Your questions doesn't deal with AJAX in particular, but the issue of using a value from an asynchronous call is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs to be async as well.
So ether also accept a callback, like this.

```
function (t, callback) {
    try {
        t.withFrame("etravelframe", function () {
            if (t.exists('#outFlight1------') == true) {
                // Callbacks usually take the error as first parameter.
                // So by using null as first parameter, we notify the callback that here is no error. 
                // And that the result (if any) is available in the second argument.
                callback(null, true);
            } else {
                callback(null, false);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        // also use the callback, async functions should work consistently
        callback(err);
    }
}
```

Or create a [deffered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object and return a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/).
Like so:

```
function (t) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred()
    try {
        t.withFrame("etravelframe", function () {
            if (t.exists('#outFlight1------') == true) {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(false);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you clarify the null parameter being passed?

Comment: @Thomas See my augmented answer